# Getting through a force field

Tags: physics

I'm writing a children's book where there is a force field over a park. I need a way for my characters to get through the force field without them totally shutting it down. I'm thinking something like a large ring (about the size of a hula hoop) that they can stick into the field that would somehow loop the energy around and keep the ring open and clear so they could get through. Is this possible? Can you think of another way? Thanks for your time and thoughts!

Comment: This is pretty broad as it stands. Force fields are completely fictional entities; they can work any way you want them to. Maybe they break down in the presence of that weird hula hoop. Maybe you can dance your way through. Maybe if you just shout at it enough, it will let you pass. Without more information about your particular brand of force field and how it operates, literally anything could work.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know if there were generally accepted rules for force fields, and I'm not a scientist, so didn't know if there were particular physics principles (even if FF aren't real) that they had to follow. I appreciate your answer and I know what to do now. Whatever I want :) Thanks

Comment: i would use a  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage if you wanna sound sci-ency after all most force-fields are in someway based of electromagnetism in sci-fi. as for not being detected, if the kids did this while it was raining or storming then the change in the FF would be masked in the white noise from the rain. it's also a good excuse for thematic weather if you need it. (a faraday cage can easily just be a big coil of copper btw)

Comment: There aren't any generally accepted rules for force fields. They don't exist, but they're common enough in sci-fi/fantasy that they don't really suspend disbelief anymore.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks, everyone. I appreciate your response and direction.

Comment: A dome shaped force field has many of the effects of a solid matter dome.  Many solid matter dome buildings have doors in them.  There could always be a gateway with a gate or door that people can go through.

Comment: If the kids have to find a way through the force field, imagine that the force field extends to a fence at the edge of the park.  There could be a dirt slope on one side leading down to the top of a tall stone wall, and the force field could reach to the fence and no farther.  Perhaps this group of kids like to travel through the slope between the fence and the stone wall, holding on to bushes and small trees to keep from rolling down the slope and falling off the stone wall.  So they found a hole or tunnel, hidden by bushes, from the slope leading into the park under the fence.

Comment: So when the kids try to get into the park when the force field is on, they travel along the slope holding on to trees and bushes (they can't hold on to the fence because of the force field) to reach the place with the hole or tunnel under the fence to see if the force field blocks the tunnel.  This is something I actually did - without the tunnel or the force field - with friends as a child.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a children's book, I'm assuming that the Cool Factor is going to be more important to the target audience than scientific rigor!

In terms of things a kid could easily understand, there are a couple possibilities.

## Option 1) Fighting force with force

If your force field is static and unchanging (like a magnet), you could use a second force field that emits a field exactly equal and opposite to the field in the location it is placed. This way, it is being "pulled" just as hard as it is being "pushed", making the net force on an item zero.

In a children's book, one possible metaphor for this would be two identical fans blowing directly at each other--a piece of paper put exactly in the middle would end up not moving at all.  It's not the best analogy out there, but at least it could be easily illustrated. (You could also use opposing magnets to explain this, although that could be a bit less intuitive.)

## Option 2) Force-canceling "headphones"

If you want your force field to seem a bit more like a dynamic, oscillating energy barrier--which might sound a little more futuristic--you could introduce a device that works a lot like active noise cancelling headphones. It would detect the field around it and spit out a field of its own that is exactly out of phase with it, nullifying it. One good thing about this is that it would work on all force fields--not just the one--and only let the wearer through.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.

The characters known you cant run through it or walk through it.  Birds hit it and bounce off.  Rain runs off of it.

But big flakes of snow go through it.  The force field is like a motion detector.  **If you move very, very slowly, it will not offer resistance.**

There is a parallel if you want to get sciency.   [Electromagnetic induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction) is an electrical force produced by a conductor within a changing magnetic field.  The faster the change the more the force.  The force produced opposes the force producing it.

Your field taps into the kinetic energy of an object hitting the field to generate a proportionately large force that repels it.  An object which is just barely moving only gets the tiniest repulsive force produced.

Comment: Oh, my goodness! Such cool ideas. You all rock. I like this one too. Could add some great comedy. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Burrow under it.** Assume that your technobabble force field does not extend underground, but it will extend the shape if somebody removes the earth on which it rests. So the trick is to tunnel in such a way that the roof of the tunnel does not collapse.

**Lift it up.** As a variant of the above, assume that if you can put your hand under a piece of sod beneath the force field, you can lift the sod and the force field will adjust itself to the new "ground" contours.

**Find a drainage pipe.** Nothing to explain.

Comment: Nice! I can see how that would work very well, and when they get chased out, they could collapse the tunnel and the bad guys would be caught when the FF extended itself. thanks!